# Check if ThemeMode.system is dark or light

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, themes

I'm working on a mobile application and I want to have ThemeMode.system by default, but I want to make it so that the user can change it. Then I have a IconButton that should have Icons.dark_mode if the system theme is dark and Icons.light_mode if the system theme is white. I tried this:

```
Icon themeIcon = Icon(ThemeMode.system == ThemeMode.dark ? Icons.dark_mode : Icons.light_mode);
```

but it turns out that ThemeMode.system can't be one of them. So, how can I set the Icon based of that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be looking for

```
Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light
Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark
```

[Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/brightness.html) is the appropriate documentation